# Unable to call geolocationerror when gps is disabled

Tags: android, ionic-framework

When gps is enabled geolocationsuccess work perfectly. But when gps diabled it not calling geolocationerror in mobile device.Working on ionic framework using phonegap geolocation for checking is gps enable or not. codes are here

```
var locOptions = {
      maximumAge : 10000,
      timeout : 5000,
      enableHighAccuracy : true
    };
function onLocationSuccess(position) {
    console.log(position);
    // alert('success');
    $rootScope.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                                     position.coords.longitude);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': $rootScope.pos}, function address(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                $rootScope.currentposition = results[1].formatted_address;
                console.log($rootScope.currentposition);
                if($scope.switchToState=='signedIn'){
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                        $http.get($rootScope.url +'api/price/?key=movo1026868hk738hkl')
                            .success(function(response) {
                                $rootScope.truckfare=response.datasets;
                            });
                    console.log('reached here2');
                        $state.go('app.home');
                    }
                    else{
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                        $state.go('start');
                    }
            }
        }
    });
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onLocationError(error) {
    alert("Geolocation error: #" + e.code + "\n" + e.message);
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onLocationSuccess, onLocationError, locOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geolocation API will not give you an error if the GPS is off because that is not an error state. It will just timeout if it is not able to get a lock in the time limit you specify.

Unfortunately, this is a real problem. If you turn off GPS and Geolocation API times out, you will not be able to make it work again unless you restart a whole application. So even if you turn GPS back online API will not work again unless an application is restarted.

There's a simple workaround here. Before you initialize Geolocation API check if GPS is online. You can do that using this PhoneGap/Cordova plugin:

https://github.com/mablack/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

Essentially, this plugin will solve your initial problem + problem I mentioned you before.

Comment: But in my case using diagnostic plugin is work for only one time after installation and after that it unable to run

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not here to hold your hand and guide you through this. I gave you a working solution, now you need to find a way and make it work. If this plugin is working only once then that's another question for StackOverflow.